# WPF TabControl not firing Loaded event of unfocused children

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `TabControl` with a binding for the `ItemsSource` property. It's bound to a `ObservableCollection`. When I add an item to the collection, the tabs get created correctly, but only the first tab gets its `Grid_Loaded` event fired. I'm guessing this is because it's focused. I need to initialize stuff when a new tab opens, it contains a control that needs to be referenced.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabSessions" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Sessions}"
                SelectedIndex="0"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Padding="0,0,0,0">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Margin="4,4,16,4" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
                <!-- View here -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Is there an event that I could use to initialize this? I also need the DataContext to be set, and the view to be initialized.c#

Answer (score 1):

The `DataTemplate` is reused by the tabs, which is why you're probably only seeing one `Loaded` event. It's only loaded the first time and then reused when you switch tabs. Only the binded content is changed.

Instead of listening to `Loaded` on the `Grid`, you could rather listen to `DataContextChanged` which will tell you every time the `DataContext` is set to a new object.

The `DataContext` will change when you switch tabs. The current tab will be set as the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` (and by extensions the `Grid`).

When using a `DataTemplate` you assume that the view is going to be the same, but the content is going to differ. If this is not the case and the views will differ based on the content, you'll probably want to look into using a `DataTemplateSelector`. This will let you define several `DataTemplate`s and select one of them to use based on the current `DataContext`. You can read up on `DataTemplateSelector` in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.7)

Comment: I thought about using the DataContextChanged event, but I need an event that fires when the tab is opened...

Comment: The `Grid` inside the `DataTemplate` is used for all the tabs, when you switch tab, the `DataContext` will change for the `Grid` and the event is fired. Alternatively you can use `SelectionChanged` on the `TabControl` itself. This fired whenever you change tab